# Can't connect to SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server SSIS ETL package. It simply looks to take data from a source db & synchronises it into a target database. Connection parameters are inserted into a XML config file. Been advised we only require SELECT/View permissions on the source but whenever we run the package we get errors stating the service account login has failed & can't open database requested by login.

On a basic SQL Server Management Studio level I can see the account has public access at the instance level but has no permission assigned at the database level. From database properties/permissions I can see the grant box has been ticked for Select access.

I'm not familiar really with how Select/View access grants work, but surely it needs to have some permission defined at the database level; should it not need `db_datareader` as a minimum?

Comment: No such thing as "detect minimum permission needed" tool (would come handy though :). So. Run Profiler and see the auth. error you get and add access one by one.

Comment: why don't you run SSMS as your service account and see if you can select tables/views you need from the source database if your are really not sure it has access?

Comment: This is now resolved. Adding the 'db_datareader' permission resolved the issue. Should note that the source database is hosted by a different function which meant I had no access to it & had to follow their guidelines.